# How i compare my old password with entered old password when they all are default encrypted by loopback.change password with old password and compare

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I do not understand how I check the old password are entered by users are matched from database passwords for change password API.

Comment: the same way you do it when you want to check if the password is ok for login

Comment: app.models.user.findOne({ where: { id: req.body.id }, }, (error, data) => {
         data.updateAttribute('password', User.hashPassword(req.body.new_password), function (err, users) {
            if (err || !users||data.password!=users.password) {
              passwordStatus = false,
                data.message = '<p class="lead">Old password wrong.</p>';
              res.render('error', data);
            } else {
              passwordStatus = true,

Comment: @LelioFaieta can you please explain on upper code flow it's based on loopback because they auto-encrypted passwords when we use req.body.password is encrypted then saved. and the problem is when I used to change password API then there is a condition if the old password entered by the user then password changed, otherwise alert display on response but when I bcrypt it and compare with loopback generated password both encryption are differ